# errors while updating raspbian Jessie os

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie

Whenever I run sudo apt-get update I get the following errors:

```
Err http://packages.openmediavault.org kralizec Release.gpg                    
  Could not resolve 'packages.openmediavault.org'
Err http://debian.froxlor.org wheezy InRelease                                 

Err http://debian.froxlor.org wheezy Release.gpg                               
  Could not resolve 'debian.froxlor.org'
Err http://archive.raspbian.org wheezy InRelease                               

Err http://archive.zfsonlinux.org wheezy InRelease                             

Err http://archive.raspbian.org wheezy Release.gpg                             
  Could not resolve 'archive.raspbian.org'
Err http://archive.zfsonlinux.org wheezy Release.gpg                           
  Could not resolve 'archive.zfsonlinux.org'
Err http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie InRelease                            

Err http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie Release.gpg                          
  Could not resolve 'archive.raspberrypi.org'
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie InRelease

Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'mirrordirector.raspbian.org'
```

I once tried to install openmediavault and zfs but did not install as it was not successful then why is it coming ?

Comment: Looks like a DNS problem to me. Does everything you try to install or update fail?

Comment: @wayjo yes that was the problem, in past I installed dnsmasq but it work properly so I tried uninstalling or disabling it doesn't work. However why it only messes up what's in terminal but not deluge or Firefox